# Backtracking results in same repeating course

Tags: backtracking

I am trying to solve a puzzle, and it has been suggested that I use backtracking - I did not know the term so did some investigation, and found the following in Wikipedia:

> In order to apply backtracking to a specific class of problems, one must provide the data P for the particular instance of the problem that is to be solved, and six procedural parameters, root, reject, accept, first, next, and output. These procedures should take the instance data P as a parameter and should do the following:
>
> 1. root(P): return the partial candidate at the root of the search tree.
> 2. reject(P,c): return true only if the partial candidate c is not worth completing.
> 3. accept(P,c): return true if c is a solution of P, and false otherwise.
> 4. first(P,c): generate the first extension of candidate c.
> 5. next(P,s): generate the next alternative extension of a candidate, after the extension s.
> 6. output(P,c): use the solution c of P, as appropriate to the application.
>
> The backtracking algorithm reduces the problem to the call backtrack(root(P)), where backtrack is the following recursive procedure:

```
procedure backtrack(c) is
if reject(P, c) then return
if accept(P, c) then output(P, c)
s ← first(P, c)
while s ≠ NULL do
    backtrack(s)
    s ← next(P, s)
```

I have attempted to use this method for my solution, but after the method finds a rejected candidate it just starts again and finds the same route, rather than the next possible one.

I now don't think I have used the `next(P,s)` correctly, because I don't really understand the wording '***after*** the extension s'.
I've tried 2 methods:

(a) in the first() function, generating all possible extensions, storing them in a list, then using the first. The next() function then uses the other extensions from the list in turn. But this maybe can't work because of the calls to `backtrack()` in between the calls to `next()`.

(b) adding a counter to the data (i.e. the class that includes all the grid info) and incrementing this for each call of next(). But  can't work out where to reset this counter to zero.

Here's the relevant bit of code for method (a):

```
    private PotentialSolution tryFirstTrack(PotentialSolution ps)
    {

        possibleTracks = new List<PotentialSolution>();

        for (Track trytrack = Track.Empty + 1; trytrack < Track.MaxVal; trytrack++)
        {
            if (validMove(ps.nextSide, trytrack))
            {
                ps.SetCell(trytrack);
                possibleTracks.Add(ps);
            }
        }
        return tryNextTrack(ps);

    }
    private PotentialSolution tryNextTrack(PotentialSolution ps)
    {
        if (possibleTracks.Count == 0)
        {
            ps.SetCell(Track.Empty);
            return null;
        }
        ps = possibleTracks.First();
        // don't use same one again
        possibleTracks.Remove(ps);
        return ps;
    }


    private bool backtrackTracks(PotentialSolution ps)
    {
        if (canExit)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkOccupiedCells(ps))
        {
                ps = tryFirstTrack(ps);

                while (ps != null)
                {
                    // 'testCells' is a copy of the grid for use with graphics - no need to include graphics in the backtrack stack
                    testCells[ps.h, ps.w].DrawTrack(g, ps.GetCell());
                    if (ps.TestForExit(endColumn, ref canExit) != Track.MaxVal)
                    {
                        drawRowColTotals(ps);
                        return true;
                    }
                    ps.nextSide = findNextSide(ps.nextSide, ps.GetCell(), ref ps.h, ref ps.w);
                    if (ps.h >= 0 && ps.h < cellsPerSide && ps.w >= 0 && ps.w < cellsPerSide)
                    {
                        backtrackTracks(ps);
                        ps = tryNextTrack(ps);

                    }
                    else
                        return false;
                }
                return false;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

and here's some code using random choices. This works fine, so I conclude that the methods `checkOccupiedCells()` and `findNextSide()` are working correctly.

```
    private bool backtrackTracks(PotentialSolution ps)
    {
        if (canExit)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (checkOccupiedCells(ps))
        {
                Track track = createRandomTrack(ps);
                if (canExit)
                    return true;
                if (track == Track.MaxVal)
                    return false;
                ps.SetCell(track);
                ps.nextSide = findNextSide(ps.nextSide, track, ref ps.h, ref ps.w);

                if (ps.h >= 0 && ps.h < cellsPerSide && ps.w >= 0 && ps.w < cellsPerSide)
                    backtrackTracks(ps);
                else
                    return false;

         }
   }
```

If it helps, there's more background info in the puzzle itself [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112057)

Comment: It looks to me that (a) is the right way. The algorithm is also correct, its a simple depth-first-search that uses the thread dedicated stack to recurse. There must be something wrong in your code. Can you share some part of it? Assuming you want a full search, you should ignore the result of `backtrack` (if any) in the `while` loop and always move to the next item.

Comment: `extension` here means another `vertex` (point) in the graph that the current node has an  `edge` (line) to. You explore this graph by starting from some vertex. You mark it as visited, and you choose one connected with an edge other vertex to visit. This other vertex must not be yet visited, else you will at some point enter in an infinite recursion. When the graph is finite and you always mark what ever vertex you have visited, it is guarantied that you will eventually complete the traversal of the graph.

Comment: I have now added some code - hope that helps!

Comment: I don't like somehow the "possibleTracks" variable, because it seems to be a global one. When you enter into `backtrackTracks` you create a new one, then you fail, go out, and then use `tryNextTrack` and expect that your "old" list is there, but its not, because it was overwritten from the level down. You have to move this variable to be local to `backtrackTracks`.

Comment: That sounds right and I've moved the list as suggested - but no change to the result unfortunately. However I have now stepped through the creation of the list and, even though it's adding a new 'ps' (with a different track each time), the resulting list (of 2 or 3 possibles) always contains the _same_ track (the last one added). I'm baffled. I even tried copying the 'ps' object before changing the track and adding to the list. It's working as if the 'board' member of 'ps' (where the various tarcks are stored) is declared static, but it's not.

Comment: Sounds more like a fundamental c# programming issue here, so maybe I should start a new question?

Comment: Another thing I see is that you do `ps.SetCell(trytrack);` on the parameter `ps` multiple times (each time the `validMove` returns true). I guess that you have to create a new object and set the cell to it, and add it to the list. You should probably remove `ps.SetCell(Track.Empty);` because its not used after return `null`, but you do the change on `ps` that might come from `tryFirstTrack`s parameter.